# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

С уважением
 Исполнительный орган Товарищества
директор ТОО «Samshit stroy»                                                                                 С. Шортамбаев

Comment: @Lyazzat, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, запятая тут нужна после "с уважением" и после "Товарищество". То есть, будет: "С уважением, Исполнительный орган Товарищества, директор ТОО..."